# ledger-cli Error: Incorrect use of thousand-mark period

Tags: ledger-cli

I have a problem with ledger-cli while trying to transfer money between accounts with currency conversion.

I have following record in ledger:

```
2020/09/04 * Transfer
  Assets:Monzo                               -149.73 GBP
  Assets:Nest                                 738.00 PLN
```

When I run `ledger -f file.ledger reg "Assets:Nest"` I get `Error: Incorrect use of thousand-mark period`. I don't use `--decimal-comma`.

Any idea what could cause the problem?

Comment: This is a question about programming and not personal finance and money. I vote to close.

Comment: @DilipSarwate This is a question about the usage of a personal finance tool. [It is on-topic.](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/127/10997)

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica We have disagreed on this kind of issue in the past and I expect that we will continue to do so in the future too.

Comment: "skipped". In the interest of world peace.

Comment: @DilipSarwate this question is not about programming, it's about personal finance tool as it was tagged with `ledger-cli`. The regular programming stackoverflow forum don't have tag "ledger-cli" because it's not programming language, nor tool.

Comment: @DilipSarwate would you regard a question about the correct formatting of a QIF for import into Quicken as being on-topic? If so, what difference should it make that the target personal finance program is CLI based rather than GUI based?

Comment: @AakashM _Read_ the answer given by the OP, and give some thought to how _anyone_ reading the OP's question and thinking about answering could have supplied the specifics of where the error was, and _what_ the error was: that the OP used a comma instead of a period in one entry? This was a question about debugging the OP's data entries and not about any issue of personal finance, but enough people with very high reputation think it is appropriate for this group and three have even upvoted it. OK, I guess that I am in the minority on this issue, but I refuse to change my opinion.

Comment: @DilipSarwate not being deliberately contrary, but "there's a comma for a period somewhere else in the file" was in fact what I was thinking...

Comment: The problem I enconter is very common problem and hard to spot, because the error message we get from the ledger-cli shows that there are problems in other, unrelated records. Sometimes the problem is different but the error message stays the same, so it may be confusing for other users as well. I use ledger-cli for couple of years now, and it took me a while and help of community to solve it. This is why I believe other people may benefit from this answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem, thanks to Martin from [Ledger-cli Google mailing group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ledger-cli/EWPFpfETWvs/ONPMxunPAgAJ). One of the records in the ledger was corrupted, I used comma instead of dot:

```
2019/07/31 * Hosting
  Assets:Nest                                 -73,80 GBP
  Assets:Reimbursements
```

The correct form is:

```
2019/07/31 * Hosting
  Assets:Nest                                 -73.80 GBP
  Assets:Reimbursements
```